# Cannot increase volume over 100

Tags: gnome, sound, volume-control

I have this problem while I have been using GNOME. I always need to increase the volume from the sound option in the settings. If the volume is already above 100 and if I use the <kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F9</kbd> buttons for volume decrease/increase resp. The volume again falls down to 100 and I have to repeat the procedure. I never had this issue in Unity 7.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sound-control app on your taskbar? If so, right-click it and select "Sound Preferences", then you can move the slider completely to the right which will give you >150.

Using the <kbd>Up</kbd> F-key you will only get a maximum of 100. If you are already at 150 and use the <kbd>Up</kbd> F-key it will actually drop your level to 100.

Incidentally, I use a ThinkPad which has Up and Down Volume keys on its keyboard, the <kbd>F7</kbd> & <kbd>F8</kbd> are for another use.

Comment: I have one volume control in the top bar but it does not solve the problem.  The problem is that even after changing it in the settings the preferences get overridden if I use any of the buttons that I have mentioned in the question.